# REG ADD Ignores /f

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, regedit

My script:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET RegPath="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.0\"

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit" /v LastKey /t REG_SZ /d "%RegPath%" /f

START RegEdit
```

Despite the inclusion of `/f`, I am always prompted to replace the entry. How can I get the REG ADD command to not prompt and just replace the entry?

Comment: Try to use `reg import`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run it as is, you'll see that the value added to the registry is actually `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.0" /f` -- including an orphaned quotation mark, and the `/f` that was intended as a separate argument.

The problem here is that you're adding too many quotes via the variable itself, not to mention in the call to the variable, and as such it's confusing `Reg` about where arguments begin and end.

Remove all those extraneous quotation marks, and it works as intended:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET RegPath=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.0\

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit" /v LastKey /t REG_SZ /d %RegPath% /f

START RegEdit
```

Comment: Thanks. Quotes in batch/bash scripts are truly the one thing I hate the most in computing.

Comment: Argh! That was sort of the issue. Actually, it was two separate issues. One was the trailing backslash in the second line is interpreted as an escape character. I do need one set of quotes in the event there are spaces in the /d parameter. This is what I ended up with that works: SET RegPath=blah REG ADD ... /d "%RegPath%" /f